# regex search for optional wildcard between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex

I have seen similar problems but I cant quite get them to work for my scenario.

I am trying to use regex to find an optional wildcard between 2 strings.
Here is an example of the strings that the regex does find correctly: `not happy`

if the string was:
`not very happy`

The code must still match both cases.

The code I have is:

`/\b(?<=not(*?).)happy\b/`

(`happy` and `very` would be variables)

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do /(not.*happy)/i ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that bit. I would limit the optional in between words to only 2 using {0,2}.  Too many extra words changes the context again.  So that "not at all happy" would be acceptable, "not like it didnt make me happy" would not be acceptable.

Comment: Did you want to do this purely in regex, or did you mind if PHP had a bit of a hand in things?

Comment: I am afraid that it has to be regex for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tweaking may be required, but this would match up to two words in between "not" and "happy":

```
/not(?:\s+\w+){0,2}\s+happy/
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I am more or less in need of. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This ...

```
/not +([^ ]* +)?happy/
```

And feel free to replace **?** with **{0,2}** (for example) to match up to 2 words between *not* and *happy*.